# Can one use both Hightlight.js and Prism.js in the same HTML to test and modify the colours?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Observation:**

I am aware of the security issue in this HTML code, but it will not be used for the site, it will only be tested to modify the colours of Highlight.js' CSS with Prism.js' same colours.

I would like to test both Highlight.js and Prism.js in the same HTML file, but the usage is similar. I am thinking about adding class name for each block element:

```html
<div class="prismjs">
  <pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
</div>

<div class="higlightjs">
  <pre><code class="language-html">...</code></pre>
</div>
```

I was trying to adjust Highlight.js and Prism.js code in JavaScript:

```js
const high = document.querySelectorAll('.higlightjs');

high.forEach(el => 
{
  hljs.highlightElement(el);
});

const prism = document.querySelectorAll('.prismjs');

Prism.highlightElement(prism);
```

It almost worked because I had to reorder the scripts, but Highlight.js removed `pre` and `code`. I need to keep them. You can get the complete HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/styles/default.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.28.0/themes/prism-dark.min.css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Realces de sintaxe</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Highlight.js</h1>

  <div class="highlightjs">
    <pre>
    <code class="language-markdown" aria-hidden="true">
    #### Cabeçalho nível 4 [#](#cabecalho){.anchor}
    Testando `código` em *itálico*
    </code>
  </pre>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/languages/markdown.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.highlightjs').forEach((el) => {
        hljs.highlightElement(el);
      });
    });
  </script>

  <h1>Prism.js</h1>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.28.0/prism.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.28.0/components/prism-markdown.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    const prism = document.querySelectorAll('.prismjs');

    prism.forEach(el => {
      Prism.highlight(el);
    });
  </script>

  <div class="prismjs">
    <pre class="demo__pre"><code class="demo-pre language-markdown" aria-hidden="true">
  #### Cabeçalho nível 4 [#](#cabecalho){.anchor}
  
  Testando `código` em *itálico*
  </code></pre>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: @testing_22, Prism.js took control over both them.

Comment: I have just updated. Check it.

Comment: You may want to read the warnings that appear in the console when you run the code...

Comment: Is it because I used `div`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it will not be used for site. Only for test to modify the colours of CSS.