# How to use 2 different versions of chart.js in same html source tag

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

I've plots build with 2 different versions of `chart.js`. one is with `3.8.0` & other is with `2.8.0`. So, I'm including both the versions in tags like this.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0"></script>   #For plot1
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>   #for plot2
```

-->Both are color plots. so whenever i use `js@3.8.0` first It's plotting `plot1 as color`. But, `plot2` I'm getting with no color's.

-->Similarly when I use `js@2.8.0` as first `src`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>   #for plot2
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0"></script>   #For plot1
```

plot1`I'm getting with`no color`&`plot2`with`color`

I get it that in Html executes `script src` line by line. is there is any way to use different `chartjs` versions at a time?. Any reference pls?

You guys want to upload the code?. It's a very big source code. So, I just want to get thoughts for my issue from the community people

`Chart.js @3.8.0` version code I'm using
Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rnsbhargav/x10qjr5k/3/

```
graph2() {

    const options = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          segment: {
            borderColor: (ctx) => (ctx.p0.parsed.y < ctx.p1.parsed.y ? 'green' : 'red')
          }
        }]
      },
      options: {}
    }

    const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, options);
},
```

[image]
So this in `chartjs 3.8.0`. Should I need to downgrade syntax?. If so how to make this code work on `chartjs 2.0` version...

I found After digging some documentation I came to know that syntax migrated for `@chartjs2` to `chartjs3` is different...

so is there is anyway

> 1. I can modify the code & get same output with `chartjs@2` version?
> 2. Is there is any way we can use `.noconflict` method we use normally on Jquery? so that i can use 2 different versions on source tags

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the old version of chart.js, store it in a variable, then load the new version also store it and then you can use both, as you can see in the example below old version filled by default and had beziercurves enabled, v3 does not fill by default and has sharp lines:

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer2" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
  <script>
    const chartOld = Chart;
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script>
    const chartNew = Chart;

    const options = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            borderColor: 'orange'
          },
          {
            label: '# of Points',
            data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
            borderColor: 'pink'
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {}
    }

    const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
    const ctx2 = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer2').getContext('2d');

    new chartNew(ctx, options);
    new chartOld(ctx2, options);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi there again  @LeeLenalee ...Let me check & try once...Thanks again for yor time!!

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.....Finally I came out from loop...thank you man 

Comment: @LeeLenalee, I have this similar problem, but the case is different. Please, can you see my question? Here is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022281/can-one-use-both-hightlight-js-and-prism-js-in-the-same-html-to-test-and-modify